# Load Web Page Into my Activity

Tags: android

OK. Have been trying for two weeks to get a simple web page I created in FrontPage (test.htm) to load into my Activity in my Eclipse Emulator. I have placed my page (test.htm) into my 'assets' folder and created the VERY simple code below.  I STILL cannot get the page to load into my Emulator. I am using an XML with WebView within a Linear Layout (myxmlfile).  Does anybody see anything blatantly wrong??  I have also tried: file:///asset/test.htm but my assets folder is asset(s) with an 's'.

```
public class Activity5 extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myxmlfile);

    WebView x = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    x.loadUrl("file:///assets/test.htm");

    }

}
```

Please HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to add this uses permission
**`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`** 
into your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your html path is not correct. It must be `android_asset` instead of `asset`:

```
x.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.htm");
```